# SSRS: Continuous timeline

Tags: reporting-services

I have data in form of value per hour, but there are no values for the hours 2,3,4 and 5. I have to display this data in a diagram:

[image]

But I want to show NULL-Values (empty bars) for the hours of 2,3,4 and 5 which I am not able to achieve. How can I do that? Is it even possible?

The x-axis is scalar from 0:00 to 24:00 but is still leaving out the hours without data.

Comment: Look on the axis properties. You don't want a category axis.

Comment: I am not using category axis - I switched already to scalar axis, but still not working.

Comment: Modify your dataset to return all the hours you want to display with NULLs (or zeros) for the values of hours that don't have any data.

Comment: I was probably wrong about being able to do that with a bar chart.

Comment: I am not able to modify the dataset. If I were this would be a suitable solution.

Comment: You've been asked to do a report without being able to add or modify datasets?  I can help you out with this if you can add a dataset.  I had the same problem and was able to fix it.  Refer to this report for more information: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93672/ssrs-line-chart-grouping-by-day

Comment: does the dataset return nulls when you run it or does it not return anything at all for the missing times?